# How to Detect Triggered Alerts in Pine Script Strategy on TradingView?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am currently working on a TradingView strategy using Pine Script, and I have set up an alert with the message and body both set to "`BUY1S`." Now, I am wondering if there is a way to programmatically detect whether this alert has been triggered within the Pine Script strategy itself.

I have gone through the TradingView documentation, but I couldn't find a direct method or variable that indicates whether an alert has been triggered. Has anyone successfully implemented a solution for this or can provide guidance on how to achieve this within Pine Script?

Here's a snippet of my code for reference:

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

// ... other strategy code ...

// Alert condition
alertcondition(condition, title="Buy Alert", message="BUY1S")

// How to detect if the "BUY1S" alert has been triggered programmatically within the strategy?

// ... rest of the strategy code ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `var` flag to see if your  alert condition has been `true` before. Set your flag to `true` if your alert condition is satisfied and then you need to set it to `false` at some time in order to use the flag again. Otherwise, it will stay as `true` forever.

> **var** is the keyword used for assigning and one-time initializing of the variable.
>
> Normally, a syntax of assignment of variables, which doesn’t include
> the keyword var, results in the value of the variable being
> overwritten with every update of the data. Contrary to that, when
> assigning variables with the keyword var, they can “keep the state”
> despite the data updating, only changing it when conditions within
> if-expressions are met.

Something like below:

```
var alert_fired = false

alert_condition = // Your logic here
alertcondition(alert_condition, "Alert")

if (alert_condition)    // If your alert is triggered
    alert_fired := true // Set your flag to true

if (reset_condition)    // Reset your flag based on some other condition
    alert_fired := false
```